# Is it possible to manage model data without running the server?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Suppose I have a python module written to do some clean job and daily maintenance. It has no view or template but simply a command line tool. Is it possible to interact with the models and db regardless of whether the server is on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can.

Look into the management commands [`shell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#shell) and [`dbshell`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell)

You would just do

```
python manage.py shell #You can call any method, modify Model objects, ...
```

and

```
python manage.py dbshell #Gives direct access to the database via command line
```

And this does not need the server to be running.

Comment: Thanks! I read that command in the django tutorial. But that way I still have to type something inside the interactive shell. Is there any way to run a .py file directly? (I think that 'manage.py' just simply set up some environment variables.)

Comment: There are many options - You might be intersted in [management commands](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-and-locales). The other option would be to actually code up a python file, and execute it in command line, which is essentially what the management command would be doing.